# How to display image from mysql in pdf using html2pdf library

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, html2pdf

I want to create PDF using HTML2PDF Library. I would like to display an image from MySQL in a pdf but it doesn't work. here my code :

```
<?php
include "../koneksi.php";
$tanggal = date('d/m/Y');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT brg_stok.id_brg, brg_stok.kd_brg, brg_stok.barang, kategori.nama_kategori, brg_stok.harga, brg_stok.stok, brg_stok.gambar, brg_stok.dimensi, brg_stok.status FROM brg_stok LEFT JOIN kategori ON brg_stok.id_kategori=kategori.id_kategori ORDER BY brg_stok.kd_brg");
```

?>

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<tr>";                                    
        echo "<td style='text-align: center; '>".$i.".</td>"; 
        echo "<td style='text-align: center; '>".$baris['kd_brg']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$baris['barang']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='text-align: center; '>".$baris['nama_kategori']."</td>";
        echo "<td>Rp.  ".$baris['harga']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='text-align: center; '>".$baris['stok']."</td>";
            //here's the problem
        echo "<td>";
            echo '<img src="../'.$baris['image'].'" alt="'.$baris['barang'].'" title="'.$baris['barang'].' "width="100" height="100" />';
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>".$baris['dimensi']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$baris['status']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
```

?>

```
<? $content = ob_get_clean(); 
   $content = '<page style="font-family: freeserif">'.nl2br($content).'</page>';
   require_once('libraries/pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
   try
   {
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L','A4','en', false, 'ISO-8859-15',array(20, 10, 20, 0));
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $html2pdf->Output($filename);
   }
   catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) { echo $e; }
 ?>
```

here's the error :
http://i60.tinypic.com/16iy4ub.png
the output isn't in the pdf form

please anyone help, thanks!

Comment: Which line is line 119 in all of this?

Comment: @tadman line 119 is in library file html2pdf (parsingHtml.class.php)

Comment: The only odd thingy I see here would be the missing semicolon in '<page style="font-family: freeserif">' => '<page style="font-family: freeserif;">'. But I doubt it would be it...

Comment: @DavidB. but if i vanish that code, it still doesn't work

Comment: @anggimery: I tried it out, the class accepts <img ... />. To debug the issue I would recommend to write the generated HTML to a file and validate this output file.